# How can I do a virtual route/redirect based on the path given in ASP.NET VNEXT MVC6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-core

I have a website that exposes several APIs at different paths, each handled by a controller specific to a section of the application, like `example.com/Api/Controller/Action?param1=stuff`, where Controller changes, but Actions remain fairly consistent.

I have several integrated devices that call these APIs. The issue is that these integrated devices cannot be changed easily, and the specific controller I want them to point to will need to change in the future.

My plan is to use something like a virtual redirect, where all the devices would call a fixed URL like `example.com/Api/VRedirect/{deviceId}/MethodName?param1=test`

Depending on the value of `deviceId`, the actual Controller that is used would change (based on some database lookup logic).

So for example, if the `deviceId` 1234 gets looked up and returns "Example", calling `example.com/Api/VRedirect/1234/Test?param1=test` would be the equivalent of calling `example.com/Api/Example/Test?param1=test` directly.

So far I have found no way of implementing this properly, the only way I have come close is by using custom routing:

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
    routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "RedirectRoute",
                    template: "Api/VRedirect/{deviceId}/{*subAction}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "BaseApi", action = "VRedirect"});
);
```

with a redirect action:

```
public IActionResult VRedirect(string deviceId, string subAction) {
        string controllerName = "Example"; // Database lookup based off deviceId
        return Redirect(string.Format("/Api/{0}/{1}", controllerName, subAction));
    }
```

This partially works for GET requests, but doesn't work at all for POST because it discards any and all POST data.

Is there any way to implement something like this? I suspect I might have to write a custom router but I'm not sure where to start.

**Update:**
I have managed to accomplish the desired behaviour using the default router by simply adding a route for each device in a loop:

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
    Dictionary<string, string> deviceRouteAssignments = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    // TODO: Get all these assignments from a database
    deviceRouteAssignments.Add("12345", "ExampleControllerName");
    foreach (var thisAssignment in deviceRouteAssignments) {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DeviceRouteAssignment_" + thisAssignment.Key,
            template: "Api/VRedirect/" + thisAssignment.Key + "/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = thisAssignment.Value });
        }
    }
}
```

However this has a few obvious limitations, such as the routes only being updated upon application startup. Performance degradation for a huge number of routes may be an issue, however I've tested 10,000 routes didn't notice any perceivable slowdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if these constraints are static and don't change, or don't change often, I would not look them up on each request but rather on application startup, and then cache the data in HttpContext.Cache or Redis or some other caching mechanism that would allow you to bypass this look on each request.  If they can be periodically updated, setup a time limit and on cache eviction reload the new set of entries.

Remember, the more routes you have, the more database lookups you'll have in the worst case situation.  So even if you need to do a lookup each request, a better solution would be to update the cache on each request.

However, if you absolutely have to do this on each request in each constraint, then you can simply do this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddEntityFramework(Configuration)
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<VRouterDbContextt>();
    //...
 }

// Note: I added the DbContext here (and yes, this does in fact work)...
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
     ILoggerFactory loggerfactory, VRouterDbContext context)
{
    // ....

     app.UseMvc(routes =>
     {
         routes.MapRoute(
             name: "VRoute_" + "Example",
             template: "Api/VRouter/{deviceId}/{action}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Example"},
             constraints: new { deviceId = new VRouterConstraint(context, "Example")}
        });
}

public class VRouterConstraint : IRouteConstraint {
    public VRouterConstraint (VRouterDbContext context, string controllerId) {
       this.DbContext = context;
       this.ControllerId = controllerId;
    }

    private VRouterDbContext DbContext {get; set;}
    public string ControllerId{ get; set; }

    public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, 
        IDictionary<string, object> values, RouteDirection routeDirection) {
        object deviceIdObject;
        if (!values.TryGetValue(routeKey, out deviceIdObject)) {
            return false;
        }

        string deviceId = deviceIdObject as string;
        if (deviceId == null) {
            return false;
        }

        bool match = DbContext.DeviceServiceAssociations
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(o => o.ControllerId == this.ControllerId)
            .Any(o => o.AssoicatedDeviceId == deviceId);
        return match;
    }
}
```

So this is a rather simple way to provide an injected repository to your manually created RouteConstraints.

There is, however, a small issue in that the DbContext must live for the life of the application and that is not really how DbContexts are intended to live.  DbContexts have no facility to clean up after themselves other than disposal of the context itself, so it will basically grow and grow its memory usage over time.. although that will likely be limited in this case if you are always querying the same sets of data.

This is because your Route Constraints are created at app startup, and live for the life of the application, and your contexts have to be injected when the constraints are created (although there are some ways around that as well, they may not be the best solution either... for instance You could do an optimization which would inject a factory that creates your context instead, but now you're bypassing the containers lifetime management.  You could also use service location, which sometimes you don't have much choice in.. but I leave that for a last resort).

This is why it's much better to query the database at startup and cache the data than to do these kinds of queries on each request.

However, if you're fine with the context (there will be only one) living for the life of the app, then this is a very easy solution.

Also, you really should use the Interface Segregation Principle as well to reduce dependencies.  This still creates a dependency on the actual VRouterDbContext, so it can't be easily mocked and tested... so add an interface instead.

Comment: Thanks very much, this works nicely. The routes do update relatively rarely, but they do need to update at runtime without an app restart, so I might implement a cache that expires every x min, as you suggested. The long life instance of the DbContext is a little concerning but given that it only ever reads data that rarely changes, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Ryan - one of the neat things about the new Convention based configuration is you can just add new parameters like that and it will inject them for you.  It won't do this for standard action methods, but oh well.  However, even if it didn't provide this nice feature, we could still likely use service location... I'm okish with using service location within configuration nodes like this as I still consider it vaguely part of the composition root (although i'm sure Mark Seemann would violently disagree).

Comment: @Ryan - if the long-lived context becomes an issue, let me know, we can find a solution to that.

Comment: While testing this with IIS on my laptop, this was working fine, however when I tested it on a slow Linux box with the Kestrel web server, I would get a database error (the call stack is getting lost so I can't get the actual error, but I think it is to do with concurrency). I think two requests coming in on different threads are calling Match in the constraint at the same time, which accesses the same DbContext concurrently. I seem to have fixed the error by adding a lock object and locking around the DbContext access.

Comment: It also appears to be happening now with ApplicationIdentityDbContext. It may be a bug with the InMemoryStore. It appears to happen at random which feels like a race condition/concurrency issue, even though the DbContexts are separate instances.

Comment: @Ryan - The InMemoryStore is only intended for Unit testing, you really shouldn't be using it for application purposes.  It doesn't have any of the concurrency support of a normal database.

Comment: Hi Erik, it' has been several months but finally the long living DbContext is giving me issues - specifically high memory usage, which grows with every request.

I am now looking at ways to get hold of the DbContext factory that creates the DbContext, and pass this into the route constraint - is this the solution you mentioned previously? So far, I can't find a way to do this with the build in dependency injection framework.

Any help would, again, be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nevermind, I seem to have figured it out: Within my Match function, I now do:

`using (VectorDbContext vectorDbContext = DbContextActivator.CreateInstance<VectorDbContext>(httpContext.ApplicationServices)) {

// use dbContext here

}`

Thank you .NET reference source!

Answer (score 1):

For this to work for POST requests, you have to use something like `HttpClient` and create a post request to the resource you want. In fact you can use `HttpClient` for GET requests too and they will be working 100% of the time.

But doing it this way is beneficial if you want to call an external API. If you just want to call internal resources, it is better to use some other pattern. For example, have you thought of doing away with all of your controllers except the `BaseApiController`? After you have received the request from the device and you want to delegate the processing to some other class, it does not have to be a controller class. You can simply create instance of the required POCO class by using `Activator.CreateInstance` (or better yet, use a DI container to instantiate the class) and invoke it's required method.

Comment: I have considered moving everything into one controller, however each existing controller uses different DbContexts which are injected into the Controllers, and I am hoping to keep them compartmentalised and separate.

HttpClient might be the way to go, however it's a roundabout way of accomplishing the solution. I think ultimately a custom IRouter that handles these paths might be the way to go but I currently have no idea how to implement that.

Answer (score 1):

Upon reflecting on it further the following might also work for you:

```
public class CustomControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override Type GetControllerType(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        var controllerToken = requestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        var context = new DbContext();
        var mappedRoute = context.RouteMaps.FirstOrDefault(r => r.DeviceId == controllerToken);
        if(mappedRoute == null) return base.GetControllerType(requestContext, controllerName);

        requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = mappedRoute.ControllerShortName; //Example: "Home";
        return Type.GetType(mappedRoute.FullyQualifiedName);  //Example: "Web.Controllers.HomeController"
    }
}
```

As you can see, your database table would contain at least three columns, `DeviceId`, `ControllerShortName` and `FullyQualifiedName`. So, for example, if you wanted /1234/About to be processed by /Home/About, you would specify "Home" as `ControllerShortName` and `YourProject.Controllers.HomeController` as fully qualified name. Please note that you will have to add assembly name if the controllers are not in the currently executing assembly.

After doing the above, you just have to register in `Global.asax`:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(CustomControllerFactory));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I can't use `ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(CustomControllerFactory));` in `Global.asax` because MVC6 applications don't use a `Global.asax` file anymore, but I've accepted your answer until I can finalize my own solution based upon it.

Answer (score 0):

So today I had an epiphany of sorts and realised that this can actually be accomplished rather trivially by using route constraints.

A single route for each of the controllers to be used is registered:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "VRoute_" + "Example",
    template: "Api/VRouter/{deviceId}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Example"},
    constraints: new { deviceId = new VRouterConstraint("Example") }
);
```

The above code is repeated once for each Controller, via a for loop or other method (in this case only the `ExampleController` is registered)

Notice the route constraint specified for `deviceId`. In order for the route to trigger, `VRouterConstraint` must register a match on the `deviceId` parameter.

`VRouterConstraint` looks like:

```
public class VRouterConstraint : IRouteConstraint {
    public VRouterConstraint (string controllerId) {
        this.ControllerId= controllerId;
    }

    public string ControllerId{ get; set; }

    public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, IDictionary<string, object> values, RouteDirection routeDirection) {
        object deviceIdObject;
        if (!values.TryGetValue(routeKey, out deviceIdObject)) {
            return false;
        }

        string deviceId = deviceIdObject as string;
        if (deviceId == null) {
            return false;
        }

        bool match = false;

        using (VRouterDbContext vRouterDb = new VRouterDbContext ()) {
            match = vRouterDb.DeviceServiceAssociations
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(o => o.ControllerId == this.ControllerId)
                .Any(o => o.AssoicatedDeviceId == deviceId);
        }

        return match;
    }
}
```

So, when a device goes to the address `Api/VRouter/ABC123/Test`, `ABC123` is parsed as the `deviceId`, and the `Match()` method within `VRouterConstraint` is called against it. The `Match()` method does a lookup on the database to see if the device `123ABC` is registered to the Controller that the route links to (in this case `Example`), and if so, returns `True`.

Comment: Are your routes static?  Or can they change at runtime?  Meaning, can you assume that when the app starts up, that all routes are defined, all deviceid's exist, and that these will not change?  Or, can you assume that they will not change frequently and thus can be cached for periods of time and refreshed every x minutes/hours, etc..?