# Dependancy Injected DbContext is empty after populating DbContext created with new (EF7, ASP.NET 5, vnext)

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, dbcontext, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am relatively new to EF7 and have heard that Dependency Injection of DbContexts into the Controller constructor is a good way to go about getting the DbContext for use within given Action methods. However, there are many situations where Dependency Injection is impossible (for example, accessing the Db in ordinary classes), and the `using(VectorDbContext dbContext...)` pattern must be used.

I have run into an issue where adding data to a DbContext created with the `using` pattern cannot be accessed by a context that was dependency injected. The DbContext is a simple InMemory database used for testing - it doesn't connect to anything.

Here is the code that adds entities to the DbContext, for testing I am calling this in Startup.cs:

```
using (ExampleDbContext dbContext= new ExampleDbContext()) {
    dbContext.Things.Add(
        new Thing() {
            Stuff= "something"
        });

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Here is the access code within the Controller:

```
public class ExampleController : Controller {
    public ExampleController(ExampleDbContext exampleDbContext) {
        this.ExampleDbContext= exampleDbContext;
    }

    public ExampleDbContext ExampleDbContext { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> ExampleAction() {

        // new DbContext:
        using(ExampleDbContext dbContext = new ExampleDbContext ()) {
            var List1 = (await dbContext.Things
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToListAsync());
        }

        // Injected DbContext:
        var List2 = (await this.ExampleDbContext.Things
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

When stepping through, List1 has the expected one item in it, but List2 is always empty!

What am I doing wrong? It appears the DbContexts aren't in sync somehow, how does Dependency Injection create the DbContext/where does it come from?

EDIT: I just did some additional testing and have confirmed that any entities added within the DbContext created with `new` are only visible in `new`, and the entities added within the Injected DbContext are only visible within the Injected DbContext, leading me to believe they are connecting to different backing databases, but I cannot confirm.

Comment: As to where the DbContext injection happens: I've implemented SimpleInjector to do this for me, following our respected S.O. member [Steven](http://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven) and his [blog](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) about how to implement it. I found his approach very usefull, maybe you can work out how to solve your issue(s) with his walkthrough!

Comment: Currently I am using MVC6's built in Dependency Injector, apparently it creates objects Per Request Scope [as detailed here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/17/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-vnext.aspx) and disposes them afterwards.

No idea why the same DbContext presents two different views of data though. Thanks for the blog link, I might implement that for some finer control.

Comment: @Ryan - It's not the same DbContext.  You created a new one.  It's two separate DbContexts, so of course they contain different sets of data in their internal caches.  I have no idea why you're creating a new instance..

Comment: @Ryan - also, you're 100% wrong (well, ok, 99.9% wrong) that "there are many situations where Dependency Injection is impossible".  You simply are not understanding dependency injection and how you're supposed to use it properly.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Sorry, it's two different DbContext instances, however they should still both provide access to the same backing database, and therefore contain the same data upon creation, given that the data was added before the creation of either. Cache should have nothing to do with it?

Also, I need access to the DbContext within a custom IRouteConstraint, which I create explicitly within ConfigureServices in Startup. Given that EF can't (by default) inject dependencies into methods, only constructors, I can't use the dependency injection provider to get a new DbContext.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I agree with you about two separate `DbContext`s, but shouldn't each of them go beyond its internal cache and query the database directly and, therefore, return the same data?

Comment: @Ryan - Again, you lack understanding of how to use dependency injection and claim you can't do this or that when what you really mean is "I don't understand how to do this or that".  First, I would suggest that needing access to a DbContext in a RouteConstraint is a very poor design and violates the Single Responsibility Principle.  You have not explained why you need this, so I can't offer a better solution.  I'm guessing you're either trying to implement some kind of multi-tenancy or you're trying to implement some kind of role based routing.  However, typically you inject a factory instead

Comment: @Sergey - That depends, he hasn't shown his DI configuration, so we don't know how his dependencies are registered.

Comment: @Sergey - Also, I believe the InMemoryStore is designed for Unit Testing, and as such keeps its own in-memory database per context, which is also deleted when the context is disposed.  I could be wrong on that though.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch My intention is to do a kind of role based routing, I actually have a question for this part of my project [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037695/how-can-i-do-a-virtual-route-redirect-based-on-the-path-given-in-asp-net-vnext-m). In terms of DI configuration, I'm using the default DI container provided in vnext as outlined [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/17/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-vnext.aspx), I'm not sure how this is configured - there appears to be very little documentation at this stage.

Comment: @Ryan - I will offer some suggestions in a few hours when I have time.  this is not a difficult problem actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong, but my assumption is that when you create a new instance of `DbContext` in code, you are using the parameterless constructor that sets underlying connection string to some default value. However, DI-injected `DbContext` could be resolved using another constructor with different connection string passed in explicitly.

That's an example of Unity config that explicitly specifies constructor parameter:

```
<register type="DbContext, [assembly-name]" mapTo="DbContext, [assembly-name]">
<constructor>
    <param name="nameOrConnectionString" value="Test"/>
</constructor>
</register>
```

So I would check a configuration of your container.

Comment: This is a definite possibility - I know that this definitely happens when the parameterless extension methods are used in the `DbContext` `OnConfiguring` for setting up the connection. I have worked around it previously by manually providing the connection string, ie `options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"));` rather than `options.UseSqlServer()`. However, it seems that `UseInMemoryStore()` has no parameterized overloads, so there's nothing I can immediately do about it... I'm going to go dig through some vNext source code.